# How to use Nginx reverse proxy to connect a public server to internal server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I am currently working on a site that is hosted from a server running in my home. Here is the setup:

1. Server running ESXi, two virtual machines
2. First virtual machine is connected publicly to the internet under a DDNS. It is running Nginx and will serve to proxy requests from the public internet to the servers that are on internal IP addresses only
3. I am performing a Wordpress installation on the internal server

Here is the Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.23/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.23/;
    }
}
```

These ports are forwarded on the home network, and that works. Here's the issue - when I try to load the site outside of my home network it seems to be making a redirect to the internal IP address (http://192.168.1.23) which is obviously failing, and not what I want it to do.

I want it to proxy all requests through the proxy server, which is set up to access the public internet. Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: This is caused by your web application, not by nginx.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, I appreciate the response